# Xamarin Forms Entry Return Type not working as expected

Tags: xamarin.forms

I tried setting the new feature in Xamarin Forms 3 which is `ReturnType` and I have set it to `Next`. My form has multiple fields and I want to make that the next Entry is focused when the **Next** button is pressed. However it just closes the keyboard. I did read the documents however I could not find the way to focus it to the next `Entry`. Can someone please guide?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those who want to know how I implemented it, it is as follows:

I created a behavior which will handle the `OnAttachedTo` and `OnDetachingFrom` so that I can handle the `Completed` event to move the focus. Now for that, I need a `BindableProperty`. I created the following code out of the logic:

```
public class NextEntryBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty NextEntryProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NextEntry), typeof(Entry), typeof(Entry), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneTime, defaultValue: null);

    public Entry NextEntry
    {
        get => (Entry)GetValue(NextEntryProperty);
        set => SetValue(NextEntryProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.Completed += Bindable_Completed;
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
    }

    private void Bindable_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (NextEntry != null)
        {
            NextEntry.Focus();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.Completed -= Bindable_Completed;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a `NextEntry` property, we use it via XAML to focus on the desired entry field once the user marks it as complete using the Next button.

XAML:

```
<Entry ReturnType="Next">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:NextEntryBehavior NextEntry="{x:Reference LastName}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

In the above behavior, the LastName reference I used is the control to which the focus should go when the user taps on Next.
This way, it worked as expected and is reusable across the project.

Answer (score 1):

the property `ReturnType` for `Entry` will only set graphically the Return Key in Keyboard to the specified type - `Next` in your case.

In order to set Focus for another Entry in the view you need to call `Focus()` from within the targeted `Entry` in the code-behind.

For Example:

```
private void txtUsername_OnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtPassword.Focus();
}
```

if you're applying MVVM pattern. You will need a property in the `Entry` to Bind on for ViewModel property. One way to achieve this is by extending `Entry` control to add a bindable property called "IsActive" and create a `Trigger` that listens for changes on this property and calls `Focus()`, like below:

```
public class ExtendedEntry : Entry
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsActiveProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(IsActive),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(ExtendedEntry),
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
        defaultValue: false);

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsActiveProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value);
    }

    private Trigger _isActiveTriger;
    private EntryIsActiveAction _activeAction;
    public ExtendedEntry()
    {
        InitTriggers();
    }

    private void InitTriggers()
    {
        InitIsActiveTrigger();
    }

    private void InitIsActiveTrigger()
    {
        _activeAction = new EntryIsActiveAction();
        _isActiveTriger = new Trigger(typeof(ExtendedEntry))
        {
            Value = false,
            Property = IsActiveProperty,
            EnterActions = { _activeAction },
            ExitActions = { _activeAction }
        };

        Triggers.Add(_isActiveTriger);
    }
}


public class EntryIsActiveAction : TriggerAction<ExtendedEntry>
{
    protected override void Invoke(ExtendedEntry sender)
    {
        if (sender.IsActive)
        {
            sender.Focus();
            return;
        }

        sender.Unfocus();
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

Xaml page:

```
<Entry x:Name="txtPassword" IsActive="{Binding IsPasswordActive}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
    private bool _isPasswordActive;

    public bool IsPasswordActive
    {
        get => _isPasswordActive;
        set
        {
            _isPasswordActive = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Khaled, thank you for the help. I just wanted to know if it is implemented automatically or we have to handle it. I am answering below the way I have implemented it. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: No problem at all.